# What should I do if I find an answer in a question but the question itself is a different problem?

Tags: discussion

I had a problem in my project (React Native + Rails). Backend keeps getting `ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)`. I googled for it for a few hours but cannot get any answer (of course trying to fix it by myself).

Eventually, I found a solution from an answer of this post: [How to upload local image file on React Native app to Rails api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334811/how-to-upload-local-image-file-on-react-native-app-to-rails-api)
.

I'd like to share this answer with others but the question itself and the title is quite different from the problem that I have. So it does not show up very well in google and SO search results with keyword of error message.

I don't think title editing is a good idea because the OP does not include the error.
I don't want to create a new post because of duplication. What should I do?

Comment: Personally I'd open a new question, then self-close as a duplicate linking to the question you found. Probably add a comment explaining that the answer on the dup answers your question, even though the title of the question is different. If this other answers happens to contain some of the same code that's needed to answer your question, but is different in spirit, I'd open a new question and self-answer, writing an answer specific to your question but crediting the answer you found as inspiration. I don't have precedent of either of those approaches, however.

Comment: @canton7 If the post is closed due to duplication, will it affect the post visibility and seo negatively?

Comment: It's possible, but I've never come across that. I'll let someone with more knowledge answer that conclusively. I don't see duplicates as a bad thing necessarily: closing a post as a dup is (IMO) just a way of directing readers towards some other good answers to the same question

Comment: duplicates act as signposts. They assist in directing users that search for different words / phrases / code / errors to the canonical q/a. That goes for both users here on SE as for visitors that come from Google.

Comment: @rene So if the question is not duplicated but an answer is, is that duplicated post too?

Comment: @bravemaster yes, you could have widely different questions that have the same answer, so that could make them duplicates. It is not common and if that happens to a question you asked it can be confusing but the duplicate notice says: *You can find your answer here*. It doesn't say: *Your question is exactly the same as this other question here*. That subtlety is often overlooked.

Comment: @rene I've just made a new post and voted to close the post as a duplicate. However, the vote description says "This question has been asked before and already has an answer.", which is not relevant to my case.

Comment: But the notice now says: *This question already has an answer here:* which does apply to your case, right?